# Comparing big numbers in Haskell to pass quickCheck

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming, difference, numerical-integration

I have made a function that calculates the definite integral of some function g from a to b using the trapezoidal rule with n number of trapezoids. 
i.e. `definiteIntegral (-4) 5 (\x -> x) 5 = 4.499999999999998`

I need to develop a quickCheck function to test my function. I want to make use of the property that a coefficient inside an integral can be taken outside and multiplied by the integral.

This is my quickCheck function:

```
prop :: (Double, Double, Integer, Double) -> Property
prop (a, b, n, random) = (n > 0) ==> abs(random * (definiteIntegral a b (\x->x) n) - (definiteIntegral a b (\x-> random * x) n)) <= marginOfError
                            where 
                                marginOfError = 1e-5
```

The problem I have is that I need the margin of error to change according to the size of the integrals. This is because while `2.8109220919999948-2.810922091999996 = -1.3322676295501878e-15`, `2.8109220919999948e15-2.810922091999996e15 = -1`.

As a result, I need to some way to check these two numbers to see if they are similar, but my current margin of error method does not work. I'm thinking I need to check either significant digits or the numbers in scientific notation that are multiplied by 10 to a power, but I'm unsure how to implement either in Haskell.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `marginOfError = random * 1e-5`?

Comment: 1. You are performing calculations with floating point arithmetic (this you can avoid simply by testing with infinite precision, i.e. `Rational`). 3. Your algorithm only approximates the integral; you must compute the error bound of the algorithm (which is typically phrased in terms of the minimum `n` required to produce a result whose error is bounded by a certain `e` - set `e` to some small number, like 1e-5). The error bound of the trapezoidal rule is well known ("trapezoidal rule error bound"). (Aside: `(n>0)==>..` is a bad way to produce non-negative numbers - use `NonNegative Integer`).

Comment: you can check relative error which will be scale independent.  Only for small numbers check absolute error.

Comment: @user2407038 Unfortunately, due to the requirements of my function, I have to use doubles. I'm seeking a solution to the problem, keeping in mind the problems posed by floating-point arithmetic error.

Comment: @JackBuckley Perhaps you have constraints which require you to eventually use floating point numbers, but surely you can run your tests with `Rational` (in other words, if the function is correct on Rational, it is also correct on Double, since Rational is strictly more precise). Even if this is somehow not true, the rest still applies - you just have to compute the error bound factoring in imprecision due to floating point error as well as approximation error (which is a significantly harder task).

Comment: Divide one number by the other and check how close the result is to 1.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute a fairly robust margin of error for two numbers is to average them, and divide by some large constant; use that as the margin of error.

```
margin :: Double -> Double -> Double
margin a b = (a + b) / (1e5) -- Increase this for more precision; decrease for less

close :: Double -> Double -> Bool
close a b = (abs (a - b)) < (margin a b)
```

Comment: This only works (in the sense of making the test pass) because (presumably) the definition of `definiteIntegral` is correct. If you pick an arbitrary margin of error, an incorrect definition of `definiteIntegral` could always add or subtract a number less than that margin of error, producing a function which passes the test.

Comment: Yes? But that is what the original post asks for. In fact, this method is functionally equivalent to the second method proposed in the question, which OP said he didn't know how to implement in Haskell.   

See:

"I'm thinking I need to check either significant digits or the numbers in scientific notation that are multiplied by 10 to a power, but I'm unsure how to implement either in Haskell."

Answer (score 0):

You could scale your *relative* acceptable margin of error, 1.0e-5, by multiplying it by the absolute value of the largest compared item. Like this:

```
import  Test.QuickCheck

prop :: (Double, Double, Integer, Double) -> Property
prop (a, b, n, random) = (n > 0) ==> abs (di1 - di2) < marginOfError * scale  where
    di1 = random * (definiteIntegral a b (\x->x) n)
    di2 = (definiteIntegral a b (\x-> random * x) n)
    marginOfError = 1.0e-5
    scale = max (abs di1) (abs di2)
```